# ruby TypeError - no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String?

Tags: ruby, eval

Im trying to eval this function and appears

this error

TypeError - no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String

```
eval("File.open('nagai.txt', 'a+') do |f| \n   f. puts parts["  +    params[:salutation].to_i + "] \n end")
```

how I could solve

Comment: Don't do that. Your code is vulnerable.

Comment: What can i do to improve it

Comment: I need pass variables

Comment: Don't use `eval()`

Comment: I agree, I'll look for an alternative thanks

Comment: I check my error only need remove to_i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is **extremely** risky and I can't see a reason for doing this in the first place. Remove the `eval` and you get this very ordinary code:

```
File.open('nagai.txt', 'a+') do |f|
  f.puts parts[params[:salutation]]
end
```

The error comes from trying to concatenate a Fixnum/Integer to a String in the process of constructing the code you then `eval`. This code is invalid and yields the same error:

```
"1" + 1
```

Ruby isn't like other languages such as JavaScript, PHP or Perl which arbitrarily convert integers to strings and vice-versa. There's a hard separation between the two and any conversion must be specified with things like `.to_s` or `.to_i`.

That fixed version should be equivalent. If you need to defer this to some later point in time, you can write a method:

```
def write_nagai(params)
  File.open('nagai.txt', 'a+') do |f|
    f.puts parts[params[:salutation]]
  end
end
```

Comment: I believe it’s vice versa: `params[:salutation]` is a string instance passed to an array expecting an integer index.

Comment: @mudasobwa Now that I read this code I realize it's a classic case of trying to concatenate string + integer + string which always generates an error. The hash is a red-herring. The strange `eval` layer adds a lot of confusion. Thanks for pointing out that I didn't have it pinned down right though.